# Using == in a function

Tags: julia

I'm getting problems with a function. 
This function is supossed to evaluate some values on an array and, if an equality gets true, then, it should return that value. 
It's not working.
Here´s my code.

```
λ = 650*10^-9     # Longitud de onda
b = 2*10^-3     #Ancho de una rendija
k = 2π/λ     #Constante
n = 1     #Número de rendijas
m = -10:10
max = []
Trash = []
o = -1:0.01:1

function Maximo(A,B,C)
    tan(B*sin(A)*C/2) == B*sin(A)*C/2

    if true
        push!(max,A)
    else 
        push!(Trash, A)
    end
end
```

Notice and excuse my poor English and my programming skills.

I just want to get the values of "o" for which the equality is true.'
I don't care about "Trash"; it's just and array I´ve made in my desperation.

Then, when I call

```
Maximo.(o,k,b)
```

It returns me a `201-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}`

Could you give me a hand, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your requirements, but I think this should be good?

```
function maximos(A, b, c)
    # make a new array of the same type as A, but with size 0
    result = similar(A, 0)  

    for a in A
        if tan(b * sin(a) * c/2) == b * sin(a) * c/2
            push!(result, a)
        end
    end

    return result
end
```

Note that you need to call it as `max = maximos(o, k, b)`, although you shouldn't name the result `max`, since that is already an existing function name in the standard library.

If you get familiar with higher order functions, you can start writing things like

```
maximos(A, b, c) = filter(A) do a
    tan(b * sin(a) * c/2) == b * sin(a) * c/2
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, amigo! It is working now. I really appreciate your help since I am very, very new on this.